# Odoo v10 wizard issue

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-wizard

While we clicked any button on wizard then it will inactive all other buttons (not clickable). This is common issue we faced with Odoo v10.

If you will take 3 buttons in wizard and each of the button will download reports in excel then after clicked on that button all button will be disabled (user can not click).

Normal Wizard[image]

After clicked any button all other button became effect less.

[image]

Is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Is this a costum wizard or one of the odoo. If so, in what module?

Comment: You can use any existing wizard also in which the wizard remain open after any action, however it's custom wizard.